# closest input inside div parent

Tags: jquery, closest

I'm am attempting to get the value of one input in a table row IF one of the other cells in the row has a value. The goal here is, if the user entered money received into the row, then a received date is required. So, on submit I want to look through all the rows and check for an entry in the current cell, then check for a date in the date cell. There are more than one row for payment entry. Here is the HTML:

```
       <div class="new_payments">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" 
                name="new_payments[<?php echo $s ?>][payment_date]"
                class="payment_date" 
                size='10' maxlength="10" 
                > 
            </td>                                
            <td>                            
                <input type="text" 
                name="new_payments[<?php echo $s ?>][credit_card]"
                class="credit_received"                               
                size="8">
            </td>  
            <td>
                <input type="text" 
                name="new_payments[<?php echo $s ?>][check]"
                class="check_received" 
                size="8">            
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text"  
                name="new_payments[<?php echo $s ?>][cash]"
                class="cash_received" 
                size="8">             
            </td>
        </tr>
    </div>
```

Here is the jQuery I am using (haven't added the check for a value in 'this' yet) to see if I am getting the expected result. Sadly, I'm getting 'undefined':

```
    jQuery('input:text.cash_received').each (function() {
       var $theDate  = jQuery(this).closest('div.new_payments').find('.payment_date').attr('value');
       alert('the closest date value is ' + $theDate );
});
```

I thought I understood the concept of go up to the parent then find the element you're looking for. Apparently not? Thanks for your excellent help!

Comment: try using `parents('div.new_payments')` instead of `closest()`

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `jQuery('input.cash_received')` or `jQuery('input[type="text"].cash_received')`? - Okay maybe :text.class works too ^^

Comment: you can also use `.val()` instead of `attr('value')`

Comment: you can't wrap a `<tr>` tag with a `<div>` tag. Any code you write for that structure more than likely won't work in all browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is tested and working. it will only alert if `.cash_received` has a value. i added values to the inputs for testing. also note the removal of the div wrapper. i added the class to the TR

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('input[type=text][value!=""].cash_received').each (function() {
        var myval= jQuery(this).parents('.new_payments').find('.payment_date').val();
           alert('the closest date value is ' +myval);
    });
});



    <tr class="new_payments">
        <td>
            <input type="text" 
            name="new_payments[<?php echo $s ?>][payment_date]"
            class="payment_date" value='this should alert'
            size='10' maxlength="10" 
            > 
        </td>                                
        <td>                            
            <input type="text" 
            name="new_payments[<?php echo $s ?>][credit_card]"
            class="credit_received"                               
            size="8">
        </td>  
        <td>
            <input type="text" 
            name="new_payments[<?php echo $s ?>][check]"
            class="check_received"
            size="8">            
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text"  
            name="new_payments[<?php echo $s ?>][cash]"
            class="cash_received" value='this input has a value'
            size="8">             
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Worked with 'closest' rather than 'parent'. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you for adding the [value!=""]. I would have struggled with that.